# integer pointer is not working while assigning two dimensional array via another pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was trying to copy the contents of one 2d array to another using pointers. I wrote this simple test program but it shows me segmentation fault but i still cannot find a rock solid reason why?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main(){
    int m[2][3]={
            {2,3,4},{5,6,7}
    };

    int *p=m;
    int *n;

    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%d \t", *(p+3*i+j));
            printf("Debug here\n");
            *(n+3*i+j)=*(p+3*i+j);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Output:
// 2    Debug here
// Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

`int *n` is an unitialized pointer, you never allocated memory for it, therefore you are trying to write your copy onto unknown territory.

You can alloc space to `n` using this:

```
int *n = (int *)malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating space for your target array.  At minimum, you should do:

```
int *n = malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof(int));
```

or

```
int n[2][3];
```

Answer (score 1):

A [pointer](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) is a variable that points to a memory location. It stores the address of the memory location. You can access that location by dereferencing the pointer using `*`.

In your case,

```
int *n;
```

This only declares a pointer to an `int`. This can point to a single integer or an array integers. You have not yet assigned any value to it (It is still not assigned a memory location). We don't know where it is pointing right now (You might not be allowed to access the memory etc.). (That's why the seg fault)

You need to allocate memory as such,

```
int *n = malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof(int));
```

The advantage of a pointer to a dynamic array than a static array

```
int n[2][3];
```

is that the pointer can be re-used (Of course you need to take care of `free`ing the existing memory before resuing the pointer [If you dont have any other access paths to the memory])

Answer (score 0):

*`reason why?`*

The destination area is not ensured

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *p=&m[0][0];
int *n = (int*)malloc(sizeof(m));
```